# Migration from one shared hosting to another throws permission error on sites/default/files

Tags: drupal, permissions, drupal-7, cpanel, shared-hosting

We have Drupal 7 installed and configured in a shared hosting(A), and now we are migrating it to another shared hosting(B), during that, sites/default/files directory throws permission error while creating files and directories inside it. We have tried to change permission of files directory to 777 temporarily but as soon as we change it, the permissions are changed back to 775 automatically. Did any one faced and solved such issue?

Comment: Try using a different tool to change the permissions

Comment: Please kindly contact your hosting provider and I believe they will solve this issue. It seems it is permission issue.

Comment: We tried different tool and it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you don't have the permission to change the directory to 777. Contact your host provider about this. It's a common problem with shared hosting; they limit the permissions of the FTP-users to avoid security risks.

The hosting company should be able to help you!